# C++ Creating a Menu and passing Args

Tags: c++, parameters, void, args

So i want to basically call a void and store my menu, Menu Number, Text, and the function(void) im defiently doing this wrong however i can't figure it out.

```
void AddMenu(char* text, int Menu, void* func)
{
        nMenu[Menu] = Menu;
        sMenu[Menu] = text;
        fMenu[Menu]* func;
}
```

So the idea would be

```
void AddMenu("Main Menu", 0, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 1", 1, SomeVoid());
void AddMenu("Option 2", 2, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 3", 3, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 4", 4, NULL);
```

is there a better way of doing this?

```
int nMenu[32];
char* sMenu[32];
DWORD* fMenu[32];

int curMenu;
bool InMenu;




void AddMenu(char* text, int Menu, void* func)
{
        nMenu[Menu] = Menu;
        sMenu[Menu] = text;
        fMenu[Menu]* func;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `struct` to hold all the data for a single menu. Then use just one array of that struct.

Comment: If you create a `struct` and create a `std::vector<myMenu>`, you can use `myMenu.emplace_back` to create the items without needing a separate function.

Comment: This is something im not familiar with to be honest. Guess i'll have to google it.

Comment: make each menu as data type , you may use struct or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```cpp
typedef void (*menuFunc)();

int nMenu[32];
const char* sMenu[32];
menuFunc fMenu[32];

void AddMenu(const char* text, int Menu, menuFunc func)
{
    nMenu[Menu] = Menu;
    sMenu[Menu] = text;
    fMenu[Menu] = func;
}
```

```cpp
void SomeVoid()
{
    ...
}

void AddMenu("Main Menu", 0, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 1", 1, SomeVoid);
void AddMenu("Option 2", 2, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 3", 3, NULL);
void AddMenu("Option 4", 4, NULL);
```

That being said, consider something more like this instead:

```cpp
using menuFunc = std::function<void()>;

struct menuInfo
{
    int id;
    std::string text;
    menuFunc func;
};

std::vector<menuInfo> fMenu;

void AddMenu(std:string text, int id, menuFunc func)
{
    menuInfo mi;
    mi.id = id;
    mi.text = text;
    mi.func = func;
    fMenu.push_back(mi);
}
```

```cpp
void SomeVoid()
{
    ...
}

void SomeVoid2()
{
    ...
}

void AddMenu("Main Menu", 0, nullptr);
void AddMenu("Option 1", 1, SomeVoid);
void AddMenu("Option 2", 2, [](){ SomeVoid2(); });
void AddMenu("Option 3", 3, nullptr);
void AddMenu("Option 4", 4, nullptr);
```

Comment: I've actually ran in to an issue which is my fault for not thinking about it. Im used to C. im not sure how to display this. for the meantime im trying to just show in console but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: @T.Shepherd my 1st example is compatible with C, my 2nd example is C++ only.

Comment: i saw that i just meant the second version however i didn't define it really sorry.